# Is it possible to run git checkout from a repository on a read only filesystem?

Tags: git, readonly

I am trying to deploy code from a bare git repository on a network mount, which is mounted read only. The first issue I ran into was during the checkout, git could not create the index.lock file. This was overcome by using the GIT_INDEX_FILE environment variable to specify a new location (temporary index file). It now appears that at the end of the checkout, git tries to create HEAD.lock.

Here is a gist of what I am trying to run:

`git --work-tree=<deploy-location> --git-dir=/nfs/<bare-git-repo> checkout <ref> -f`

Is there any way to do this if the git repo is in a read only filesystem?

Comment: Doesn't checkout assume write operations to target by definition?

Comment: The target location of the checkout is writeable. The filesystem the git repo is on is read-only.

Comment: Interesting question. It would be nice if there were an option to disable all locks, for cases like this where you're certain they won't be necessary, but I don't know if anything like that exists.

Comment: did you consider [git-new-workdir](http://nuclearsquid.com/writings/git-new-workdir/)?

Answer (score 2):

You want to clone the repository, instead. I don't think it requires write-access, since git can clone a repository via HTTP. If someone is able to write to a filesystem, via HTTP, we're all in big trouble.

Set up a tiny web server, serving the filesystem space from the read-only filesystem, and tell git to clone the URL that points to the read-only directory.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The particular issue I'm having is deploying the code where it is not acceptable to have a writable git repo in the deployment location. I would like to find a way to deploy via git checkout, where there is no chance the server being deployed to could write back to the repo I'm checking out from (I understand this may seem excessive but it is a constraint I am dealing with). Unfortunately it looks like it is necessary for git write to some files (particularly HEAD) after a checkout - which makes sense, just wondering if there is *any* way around that.

Comment: git clone accomplishes the same thing as git checkout, for your purposes. Did you actually try using git clone?

Comment: As far as I understand, the OP doesn't need HTTP at all since he can already read the repo as a mounted filesystem. So, clone /path/to/nfs/mounted/dir perhaps with the --shared option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git archive` to do this, but unlike `git checkout` you will need to start with an empty destination.

```
git --git-dir=/nfs/<bare-git-repo> archive <ref> | (cd <deploy-location> && tar xf -)
```

For deploying repeatedly, you might want to create a new directory, deploy to it, and then switch a symlink to the new location, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

export GIT_DIR=/nfs/<bare-git-repo>

DEPLOY_TO=<deploy-location>
DEPLOY_DIR="${DEPLOY_TO}-$(date +%Y%m%d.%s)"

echo "Deploying to $DEPLOY_DIR from $GIT_DIR"

mkdir "${DEPLOY_DIR}" && \
        git archive "${1:-master}" | (cd "${DEPLOY_DIR}" && tar xf -) && \
        ln -snf "${DEPLOY_DIR}" "${DEPLOY_TO}"
```

If `DEPLOY_TO` were set to `/tmp/deploy`, this would create paths like `/tmp/deploy-YYYYMMDD.*/` and set the symlink `/tmp/deploy` to point to the last one created.